# How to use warpAffine function in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, affinetransform

I need to warp an image by using an affine transformation. The error I get is that the "code has crashed".

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
Mat imgAffine, image, par;
image = imread("/media/sf_vbox_share/ubuntushare/board.jpg",1);

par.at<double>(0,0)=  1.01121;  //p1
par.at<double>(1,0)=  0.21067;  //p2;
par.at<double>(0,1)= -89.69693; //p3;
par.at<double>(1,1)= - 0.11557; //p4;
par.at<double>(0,2)= 1.44982;   //p5;
par.at<double>(1,2)= -193.66149;//p6;

imgAffine = Mat::zeros(image.rows, image.cols, image.type());
warpAffine(image,imgAffine,par, image.size(),INTER_LINEAR);
namedWindow("image",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("image",imgAffine);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`par` is undefined in size so when trying to write elements to it, it is most likely giving you segmentation faults.  Try allocating the memory for it first before setting its elements:

```
// Your code
Mat imgAffine, image, par;
image = imread ("/media/sf_vbox_share/ubuntushare/board.jpg",1);

// New code
par = Mat(2, 3, CV_64FC1); // Allocate memory

// Rest of your code
par.at<double>(0,0)=  1.01121;  //p1
par.at<double>(1,0)=  0.21067 ;  //p2;
par.at<double>(0,1)= -89.69693; //p3;
par.at<double>(1,1)= - 0.11557;  //p4;
par.at<double>(0,2)= 1.44982;   //p5;
par.at<double>(1,2)= -193.66149;//p6;
//
// ....
// ....
```

Alternatively, you can use the constructor of `cv::Mat` when declaring `par`, so at the beginning of the code:

```
Mat imgAffine, image;
Mat par(2, 3, CV_64FC1);

// Rest of your code
image = imread ("/media/sf_vbox_share/ubuntushare/board.jpg",1);

//
// ....
// ....
```

Comment: thank you. now it is working perfectly. I need to implement an interpolation function (linear or bicubic). Can you suggest me any sample code, how to detect newly created pixles and how to give them the new value according to respective formula..

Comment: That's a new question. However try here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10720586/3250829. If I've answered your question, please consider accepting the answer to let the community know you no longer need help. That's done by going to the top of this post, to the left below the up and down arrows and clicking on the checkmark icon. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion that is some what helpful, but I am unable to understand how to locate the newly created non integer coordinate pixels. I got getrectsubpix does this. But I am unable to understand How to use it.